# Implement the setSelectedIndex to tabBarController with presentmodalview to the tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am using ARC and Storyboard in my iphone application. I have simple input text view with button, On clicking button I am implementing presentModalvuewcontroller to a mainview with Tabbarcontroller. It is working fine. Now I need to conditionally implement setSelectedIndex:1 to tabbarcontroller Here is the code I am using:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ViewController *viewCon = (ViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTab"];
   viewCon.tabBarController.selectedIndex= 1;   
[self presentModalViewController:viewCon animated:YES];
```

It is working properly.Just not changing the tab. It is displaying on default 0 tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewDidLoad of ViewController add this line:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

EDIT : call this selectedIndex only when coming from previous view's button click.

Make one property BOOL flag; in appDeleagete.

Now intially it will be self.flag = FALSE; in application didFinishLaunching.

So on previous view's button click.

```
-(void)btnBackClicked:(id)sender
{
   AppDelegate *objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   objAppDelegate.flag = TRUE;
   ........
}
```

Now In viewDidLoad of ViewController add these lines:

```
 AppDelegate *objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if(objAppDelegate.flag)//if from previous then only tabbar has selected index 1
{
  self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, That will work but I need to call this selectedIndex only when we are coming from previous view's button click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; // Your desired index
```

The tabBarController property is built in to UIViewController.

Or

Do the following, before trying to change tab:

```
UITabBarController *tab=self.tabBarController;
```

And if you have used navigation controller then

```
UITabBarController *tab = self.navigationBar.tabBarController
```

And then

```
if (tab){
   NSLog(@"I have a tab bar");
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
else{
   NSLog(@"I don't have");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but no impact on the functioning.